Telegram webapp stars purchase integration
I'm trying to design React.js + Tailwindcss WebApp for Telegram messenger.
I'm curious, how can I make integrated purchases in WebApp with telegram stars.
I need it to be inside the webapp, not as bot message. (Look image example).
Highly appriciate any ideas <3
example
